# What's the "ethics" tag about?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have been looking for tags to provide tag wikis for, and I found the tag [ethics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics). It has no tag wiki yet.

What I don't understand is, what's the tag for exactly? Merriam-Webster tells me,

> **ethics** *plural in form but singular or plural in construction* :  the discipline dealing with what is good and bad and with moral duty and obligation

In what way is such a tag a good tag for chemistry SE? Considering the fact it has only one question tagged under it, it's probably created by @andselisk, though the reason is unknown to me.

I wish to have a discussion about whether this tag is necessary or not, since I'm unsure about this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're a bit too fast asking this question. The tag has not been alive for much more than three hours, and I would have caught it in one of my checks eventually. It is now a relic of the past, as I removed it immediately.

My reasons are essentially that in which ever way you look at it, it becomes a meta tag, or it would indicate that the question is more about academic conduct and therefore more likely belongs to Academia.se.

For future reference: If you find such strange tags, bring it up in chat. Everybody with more than 300 reputation can suggest tags, that does not mean we have to keep them.

I regularly clean out one-taggers that accumulated over the past weeks, so I would have found it in no time.

Comment: Sure thing @Martin.

Comment: @Martin Blame on me, I used that tag [yesterday](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76950/single-crystal-x-ray-diffraction-experiment-backwards). I wasn't even sure about proper SE subsection, so I introduced new tag just in case. If this was a bad idea, would you please point me to where I can read about introducing new tags?

Comment: @andselisk don't worry about it. We all learn something new as we use this site. It's always preferred to use existing tags over creating new ones. If you think a new tag is necessary, come over to meta and make a discussion about it.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal I'm not a very creative person, but I guess meta is going to be populated with my raised tag-questions as chemists say "periodically". Thank you for clearing the stuff up!